# This sampel code 4-6 dynamic_dispatch.py starts a server and quickly shuts it down.

Tags: python, tcp, server, twisted, dynamic-dispatch

This is supposed to create a calender server on port 10310. Sadly the code runs and quickly exits with no errors. What could be the issue? According to the twisted O'reily book I am reading I should be able to go to localhost:10310/2013 and see a small calendar.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource, NoResource
from twisted.web.server import Site

from calendar import calendar

class YearPage(Resource):
    def __init__(self, year):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        self.year = year

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body><pre>%s</pre></body></html>" % (calendar(self.year),)

class CalendarHome(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        if name.isdigit():
            return YearPage(int(name))
        else:
            return NoResource()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>Welcome to the calendar server!</body></html>"

print("pop")
root = CalendarHome()
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(10310, factory)
reactor.run
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: `reactor.run` should be `reactor.run()`. See [this page](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2010/08/learning-twisted-baby-steps-reactor.html), for example. `reactor.run` is a function, `reactor.run()` calls the function.

Comment: @unutbu litterally just saw that as i stared at it for the 15th time. This link is also  a really great resource though thank you. Can I put your "comment" as a solution to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reactor.run` should be `reactor.run()`. See [this page](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2010/08/learning-twisted-baby-steps-reactor.html), for example. 
`reactor.run` is a function, while `reactor.run()` calls the function.